# Float login form to right of the nav

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I am trying to make it so the navigation items are centered and a quick login form is aligned to the right of the navigation bar, I have tried float: right however that adds it to the next line, display: inline-block has no joy either.

Am I missing something extremely obvious or is this difficult to achieve with just HTML and CSS.

Thanks

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
nav#navBar {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
}

nav#navBar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#navBar ul li {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

nav#navBar ul li a, visited {
  color: #191919;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px;
  display: block;
}

nav#navBar ul li a:hover {
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

nav#navBar ul.loginForm {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="loginForm">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert username" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Insert password" />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change css as below.

```
nav#navBar {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

nav#navBar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav#navBar ul li {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

nav#navBar ul li a, visited {
    color: #191919;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px;
    display: block;
}

nav#navBar ul li a:hover {
    color: grey;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}

nav#navBar ul.loginForm {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

and there is no change in html.